# Itchy Shins! Footwear or Shin Splints?

Tags: lifestyle, allergen, clothes, itching

Again, Im not quite sure if this is the place to ask this question. However, I am experiencing so discomfort with my shins itching constantly. Im in two minds as to what could be causing it, as I participate in skateboarding frequently I thought this could either cause shin splints and/ or cause irritation just by purely knocking my shins constantly. (which is unfortunately inevitable when skating).

On the other hand though, I have not been active on my skateboard for a few months and the itching persists. I must also add that I play drums frequently... May that have an impact? I now think it maybe due to the boots I wear... they go above the ankle maybe an inch and are woollen on the upper, I also wear thick socks, I find once I remove my socks on a night the itching resides...

Can anyone provide me with any advice on how to combat this issue... I have often considered commuting everywhere barefoot, obviously that isn't very practical.

Comment: It very hard to find the reason of it but I suggest that you may do trial and error for every reason you gave in your question.

Comment: It could be due to your laundry detergent as well. Perhaps the skin on that portion of your body is just a bit more sensitive to it.

Answer (score 3):

[Shin splints](http://www.ehealthstar.com/conditions/shin-splints) is dull, burning or throbbing **pain** (not itch) on the **inner (medial)** side of the shin in one or both legs. It appears at a certain time after onset of an exercise and typically resolves quickly (within 15 minutes) after stopping exercise. Only in severe cases, it can persist during rest.

Shin splints do not appear as a long-term consequence of frequent knocking to the shins, but as an acute response to vibration stress, like during running.

Socks or tightly laced shoes can cause itch, either because of tightness, in which case some swelling would be visible, or because of irritation by the fabric.